# Strange SQL Server Error/Warning

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012. The procedure works fine and does execute, but I'm just curious, why is it showing this squiggly line below the procedure name?

Below is the image showing my stored procedure:

[image]

Comment: how do i supposed to see what is on a picture? Could you post code and error?

Comment: That's intellisense, I wouldn't worry about it. There is probably a refresh interval or something like that before it updates itself.

Comment: what happens when you hit **execute**?

Comment: @KamranAhmed dont worry about it...

Comment: CONTROL + SHIFT + R to update the intellisense

Comment: Hmmm
Actually, it was the intellisense problem, I refreshed and the line went away. Thanks twoleggedhorse @bew and every one who responded :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, intellisense in SSMS isn't the greatest. This stored proc must be new and SSMS hasn't "learned" about it yet, even though it clearly exists. If you were to close SSMS and reopen it, you wouldn't have this issue. I have been so frustrated with intellisense in SSMS that I've been tempted to just turn it off.

You can also press Ctrl + Shift + R to refresh the local intellisense cache, and that should take care of it.

Answer (score 3):

Press ctrl+shift+R to refresh local intellisense cache and that line will disappear.

Raj